# unison only works from macOS to debian not vice versa - zsh:1: command not found: unison

Tags: ssh, zsh, unison

I can sink my files from mac to other devices, however vice versa I get the following error:

```
   unison /home/debianuser/sync ssh://macuser@workingip/Documents/insync
   zsh:1: command not found: unison
   Fatal error: Lost connection with the server
```

interestingly I can ssh into my mac from my debian pc and run the unison command from there

I already tried to install unison from various sources to my mac, currently it is the latest brew version, brew linked it.

Comment: It appears that the `unison` command is not in the PATH of `macuser` when `macuser` ssh's into the machine. Try running `ssh macuser@workingip "which unison"` to confirm this. [Maybe this Q&A is helpful](https://superuser.com/q/1484960/228569). My expertise is thin here.

Comment: When I ssh into my mac I and type "which unison" i get "/usr/local/bin/unison"